# Phpstorm hotkeys work only on one input source

Tags: shortcut-keys, java, openjdk

I'm encountering a problem when using Phpstorm IDE on Ubuntu.

While there's two input sources enabled on my system: English and Arabic, hotkeys work just fine when English is chosen, but **when I switch to Arabic, hotkeys stop working. so I've to switch to English every time I want to use hotkeys** and this is *frustrated*. This problem does not happen when I try Phpstorm on *Windows*.

Some information:

> PhpStorm 2016.2.1
>
> Build #PS-162.1889.1, built on August 23, 2016
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 amd64
>
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

System: Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved using this package: 
https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/ubuntu/java-non-latin-shortcuts